# Obtener el valor de una columna dependiendo del valor máximo de otra columna

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo un Dataframe con datos de todos países.
Hay muchas columnas, entre ellas `Country`(nombre del país), `Surface`(superficie) y `Continent`(continente).

El problema es el siguiente: Quisiera obtener el país mas grande de cada continente.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("countries.xlsx")

continentMaxSurface = df.groupby(["Continent"])["Surface", "Country"].max()
print(continentMaxSurface)
```

Esto me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
            Surface                Country
Continent
Africa      2381740.0               Zimbabwe
America     9984670.0  Virgin Islands (U.S.)
Asia        9596900.0                  Yemen
Europe     17125191.0           Vatican City
Oceania     7741220.0      Wallis and Futuna
```

Como se ve, en `Country` no obtengo el país al cual le pertenece el dato de `Surface`, sino que obtengo al ultimo país ordenado alfabéticamente. Mi idea es que, por ejemplo, en América, en la columna `Country` obtener el valor de Canadá, ya que es el país mas grande de ese continente y la cual le pertenece el valor presentado en `Surface`.

Desde ya, gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

El secreto está en utilizar [`pandas.DataFrame.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) para encontrar el índice en la fila que tenga el valor máximo.

Puedes agrupar por continente y obtener el índice del valor máximo de la superficie, luego utilizar ese índice para hacer un `loc` del `dataframe` original y así obtener únicamente las filas que deseas.

**Nota:** Como no pusiste tus datos cree un `dataframe` genérico. Recuerda siempre agregar tus datos para que las respuestas reflejen lo que deseas obtener.

Ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Continent': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
                   'Country': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
                   'Surface': np.random.randint(1,30,6)})

# Mostramos el dataframe generado
print(df)

# Seleccionamos las filas deseadas
df1 = df.loc[df.groupby(['Continent'])['Surface'].idxmax()].reset_index(drop = True)

# Mostramos el dataframe resultante
print(df1)
```

Esto imprime:

```
  Continent Country  Surface
0         A       a        2
1         A       b       23
2         B       c       11
3         B       d       27
4         C       e       28
5         C       f        8
  Continent Country  Surface
0         A       b       23
1         B       d       27
2         C       e       28
```

Comment: Esto era lo que buscaba. No conocía el uso de la función de idxmax. Muchas gracias por tomarte tu tiempo!

Comment: No hay de que, saludos!